# In which form event I can hide label of user control

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

In a windows application project I have a form which used a user control. I want to hide a label and textbox on user control. In which event of form I can do this ?

This method in user control which named DoctorPermissionApprove:

```
public void LoadDoctorPermission(int fromWhere)
        {
            if (fromWhere == 0) // Başhekimden geldiyse?
            {
                labelDoctor.Visible = true;
                editDoctorWithoutHead.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (fromWhere == 1) // Normal Hekimden geldiyse
            {
                labelDoctor.Visible = false;
                editDoctorWithoutHead.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

And in form:

```
private void ExistRequestAndNewEntryForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = new DoctorPermissionApprove();
            obj.LoadDoctorPermission(0);
        }
```

For example I tried in shown event. But it still visible

I want to hide or show this components when the anybody open the form

Thank you a lot

Comment: In all events. You have to be more specific.

Comment: There are no restrictions on which events for which your event handler method can set a `Control.Visible` property value. What are you actually trying to ask?

Comment: Probably I can't state my problem because of my insufficient English.

I have a form. And in this form I am using a User Control from another businnes layer. When the form open, I want to show or hide label in user control. I tried to use load and shown event, but it did not work.

Comment: **What** didn't work? Show a (small and relevant) piece of your code.

Comment: Please put the code into the question, properly formatted! And DO tell us in what way it _didn't work_?! (Crashes, still visible, unreliable...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UserControl class add a public property to set the internal label visibility true or false. This can be accessed from your parent form where your usercontrol is added.

Example:

```
public class YourUserControl
    {
        //This code will be in designer class 
        private Label lblYourLabelToHide = new Label();


        //Create this public property to hide the label
        public bool IsLabelVisible
        {
            set { lblYourLabelToHide.Visible = value; }
        }


    }

    public class YourParentForm
    {
        //This will be in designer
        private YourUserControl userControl = new YourUserControl();

        public void Form_Load()
        {
            //based on some criteria
            userControl.IsLabelVisible = false;
        }
    }
```